# Controlling one element inside an array

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an edit feature to my todo-list but i'm kind of stuck and receiving a weird behaviour.

I'm filtering the array using the id's but what happens is that the entire array is changing instead of one element inside of it.

What supposed to happen is when clicking the edit button, the element im clicking on should change to an input (not the entire array)

thanks for any kind of help!

App:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./UI/Header";
import TodoList from "./Components/TodoList";
import AddTodo from "./Components/AddTodo";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [editTodo, setEditTodo] = useState(false);

  const onAddHandler = (text) => {
    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      {
        name: text,
        id: uuidv4(),
      },
    ]);
  };

  const deleteTodoHandler = (id) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
  };

  const editTodoHandler = (id) => {
    todos.filter((todo) => todo.id === id);
    setEditTodo(!editTodo);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <AddTodo onAddHandler={onAddHandler} />
        <Header />
        <TodoList
          todos={todos}
          deleteTodoHandler={deleteTodoHandler}
          editTodoHandler={editTodoHandler}
          editTodo={editTodo}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TodoList.js :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Todo from "./Todo";

const TodoList = (props) => {
  return (
    <Todo todo={props.todo}>
      {props.todos.map((todo) => {
        return (
          <p>
            {props.editTodo ? <input /> : <span>{todo.name}</span>}
            <button onClick={() => props.deleteTodoHandler(todo.id)}>
              Delete
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => props.editTodoHandler(todo.id)}>Edit</button>
          </p>
        );
      })}
    </Todo>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: setEditTodo(!editTodo); - Better practice is to use a function in cases where your next state is dependent on previous state.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `editTodo` property to true, the `TodoList` component re-renders and loops through the `todo` array again, changing every `<span>` to an `<input>`. You're going to have to pass the id of the todo that you want to edit, and add a condition to only change that single item to an `<input>`.

Comment: In addition, better to pass an array of values where each array points to one todoList. Or you might want to keep the edit function inside your list component itself.